# suggestion for receiving tcp settings for a specific service

Tags: linux, networking, proxy, nis, yellow-pages

I have some price subscriptions that require clients to know which tcp server and port to use to get them.  For example, for MSFT one might need to connect to 192.168.5.6:4500.

I have been wondering how to best store/retrieve this info so both servers and clients could share the same settings.  Some ideas like using dns entries, proxies, yellow pages, or else might work but i'm not 100% sure.  Some have suggested to me to use db tables but maybe there is some way to retrieve this with some simple tcp messages to some service out there.  Ideally it should work with Window and Linux clients.

What do you guys suggest?

ps.  It would be cool to also know of backup server settings in case the primary one is down so querying for MSFT could return a list of settings to use.

Comment: This question is too vague to be answered. Please give some background and context for what you're trying to accomplish, with concrete examples.

Comment: Let's say i want to subscribe to MSFT prices and to do so need to connect to 192.168.5.6:4500.  To get CSCO prices i need to connect to 192.168.6.7:6700, etc.  I would like a service that i could do a query and pass MSFT and retrieve a list of settings to use.  A dns query only returns an ip address as far i know.  Maybe a proxy query would work but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

I just read about [LDAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightweight_Directory_Access_Protocol) and it seems like it should work.